# What is the Correct Edition of Baluzius' Commonitory of St. Vincent Lerins?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, reference-request, book

Fr. John Shanahan's 1833 translation of [*The Commonitory*](https://ia903106.us.archive.org/1/items/commonitoryofsai0000unse/commonitoryofsai0000unse.pdf) contains the following:

[image]

QUESTION: What is ``the Correct (Latin) Edition of Baluzius''; and (if possible) where may I find it?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be this (though there's no preview available): https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sancti_Vincentii_Lirinensis_Commonitoriu/1E3nvQEACAAJ?hl=en

Comment: @brianpck Thank you for providing this link.